# Is it possible to get a unique id of nearby Bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth, public, uniqueidentifier, mac-address

I looked around and read about MAC addresses on bluetooth devices. Is this only accessible by device owner? Can it be accessed by nearby devices?

Is it possible to get a list of nearby bluetooth devices (specifically smart phones) by their unique ID without pairing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Getting a list of nearby Bluetooth devices is called the discovery process (for BT "smart ready" devices). If you talking about BT "smart" devices - you can just listen on the fixed advertising channels.
None of the methods above will guarantee that you will get all devices around you - since these nearby devices can be in a state where they do not respond to discovery request or they don't advertise.